# What is the fastest algorithm to get the max. distance of an 2d outer contour to an 2d inner contour?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, distance

What is the fastest algorithm to get the max. distance of an 2d outer contour to an 2d inner contour?

(Distance is defined by by drawing radial straight lines from one contour to another, the length of the lines defines the distance)

The two contours are not intersecting and the inner contour lies complett in the outer contour.

Currently the countours are build up from linesegments and circlesegments
(but if possible (2d-)splines should also be possible in future).
(Something like http://inspirehep.net/record/1217658/files/figure7.png)

Comment: define distance here. Is the cross a central point you want to use to calculate the distance between the 2 contours (by drawing radial straight lines)? If so, maybe the way to go is to find the max of the function defined on [0, 2*pi[ that gives the distance for each of these lines.

Comment: @Joffrey I think a distance for a point on the inner contour is the shortest distance to any point on the outer counter, and vice-versa (you shouldn't prefer any direction really). So the naive approach would be, for every point on inner/outer countour, find closest point from the other once. Return highest of those values.

Comment: The definition of distance between two figures is MINIMAL distance between all pairs of points taken from both of these figures. So, your sentence about MAXIMAL distance is absolutely non understandable. Define it, please.

Comment: @Gangnus What do you not like about my definition?

Comment: @luk32  comment without address is addressed to the post owner. I have nothing against your definition. But it is YOUR definition, not one of the question's author. That is the problem.

Comment: @Gangnus Oh, okey. I just thought there is no other logical way to define it. My bad indeed :).

Comment: @luk32 I could define maximum distance between figures as maximum distance taken through all pairs of points of both figures. It is different from yours, but gives sense, too.

Comment: @Joffrey: i have analytic curves which means there are infinit number of points. Yes i could do some segmentation of the analytic curves, but than the result depends on the length of the segments (=distance of points). If the segements are to large the result will be far away from the real result. This is wannt i wannted to avoid. Thats why i asked. Thougth this is a problem which is already solved.

Comment: @luk32 Your definition is probably the most common one indeed, but since the OP didn't mention anything, and since I saw a particular point in the figure, I felt like asking the OP to define it.

Comment: @user1911091 OK, but we still don't know your definition of the distance.